# Word for a result/achievement so exceptional that it is impossible?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, metaphors

I am looking for a word or phrase regarding something that is "impossible". I can't seem to put my finger on it, but I am trying to think of the word to describe something that is the top of the top, and thus impossible to achieve?

The only two words I have come up with are *elusive* and *formidable*, neither of which really mean what I want them to mean. I want something more clever to put it plainly.

Comment: Why not just enter "impossible synonyms" on Google? It'll give you a whole bunch in first link.

Comment: Can you give us a sentence with a blank where the word should be?

Comment: "impossible to achieve" unachievable?

Comment: By the way " I can't seem to put my figure on it" is more usually " I can't seem to put my finger on it".

Comment: It took you a bunch of words to describe this; sometimes that's the way languages work. A great thing about language is two words will often do: utterly unattainable", etc, with the adverb clinching the deal.

Comment: I can't figure out from your description if you literally mean impossible, as in no one will ever achieve it, or if you're using the word "impossible" hyperbolically; the phrase "top of the top" refers to something extant, so by definition it isn't impossible?

Answer (score 2):

[Synonyms](http://bfy.tw/hhM)

Phrases:
**(when) pigs fly**
**(when) hell freezes over**

Answer (score 1):

***[Unassailable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unassailable)*** sounds like it might fit the bill.

> 1. Impossible to dispute or disprove; undeniable: *unassailable truths*.
> 2. Not subject to attack or seizure; impregnable: *an unassailable fortress*.

thefreedictionary.com

---

Example sentence:

> *Liverpool football club are still looking **unassailable**.*

Which is synonymous with:

> *Defeating Liverpool football club still looks **impossible***.

Answer (score 1):

**[Unattainable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unattainable)**

> Not able to be reached or achieved:
>
> *an unattainable goal*

Answer (score 0):

[**Herculean task**](http://www.idioms.online/herculean-task)

> A herculean task is an extremely difficult task; an almost impossible
>   undertaking.